# How can I align the text in Text and pushbutton controls while coding in XMADL?

Tags: mobile

I have defined a control in the screen whose width is 2 times of the width of the text. How can I align text in the center?

```
<control type="TEXT" x="2" y="24" width="35" height="12" appearance_name="black" word_wrap="1" data_type="VARCHAR" default_value="Welcome!!!"/>
```

The appearance used with the text control is

```
<appearance name="black" font_family="Sans-Serif" font_name="Helvetica" font_size="3"                 font_color="#000000" background_color="#FFFFFF" alpha="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alignment is defined in the appearance using the attribute “justify”. If you want the text to be center aligned, add the attribute justify=CENTER

```
<appearance name="black" font_family="Sans-Serif" font_name="Helvetica" font_size="3" font_color="#000000" background_color="#FFFFFF" alpha="0" justify=”CENTER”/>
```

The attribute "justify" can take the values = { LEFT, RIGHT, CENTER }

You can find more information about appearance here.